# Disconnected Limbs when Auto-Rigging

Tags: blender, mesh, rigging

I'm new to Blender and rigging, and I probably have a fundamental misunderstanding of something.

In Blender, I created a humanoid model, following directions from a Blender/Unity book. The model only has 14 parts: Torso, Head, Arms/Hands (6 parts), Legs/Feet (6 parts). All body parts are children of Torso in the tree structure you'd expect (Torso > Upper Arm > Lower Arm > Hand). All body parts are overlapping in the model as well, looking pretty typical in T-pose.

[image: Blender Model]
[image: Blender Collection]

However, when I import my model into Mixamo or AccuRIG, my model is partially disassembled with Lower Arm and Hand connected from Torso, placed below the model. Lower Legs are also separated, as well as Feet.

[image: Bad Day at the Office for Space Marine]

I tried moving body parts closer together, but this didn't help, and as mentioned, I tried AccuRIG and Mixamo, which both give the same results. I'd love any suggestion of how to fix my issue!